# Ошибка при скачивании библиотек pip3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, pip

Вот такой вывод мне выдает, когда пытаюсь установить turtle с помощью `pip3 install turtle`:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting turtle
  Downloading turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-g5kalqp9/turtle/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-g5kalqp9/turtle/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-fzpah_t_
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-g5kalqp9/turtle/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-g5kalqp9/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Что мне делать? OC - Linux Lubuntu 18.04.4

Comment: А точно ли нужна эта библиотека? Судя [по странице на PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/), последняя её версия вышла 11 лет назад, поэтому она доступна только для Python 2, вы же пытаетесь установить в Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это значит, что пип пытается поставить библиотеку для второго питона. В данном случае — ничего делать не надо, `turtle` и так подефолту стоит у вас. ;) А если нет, то `sudo apt install python3-tkinter`.